# How to set combination of key codes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code for replacing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key with <kbd>TAB</kbd> key :

```
function EnterTab() { if (event.keyCode == 13) event.keyCode = 9; return false; }
```

I want to know what can I do if I want replace right arrow key with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(event.keyCode == 39){
    event.shiftKey = true;
    event.keyCode = 9;
    return false;
}
```